# Dir.glob recursive file search and stop at occurence and back up a directory

Tags: ruby, recursion

I want to dynamically look through a with possibly many subfolder for a file. This file could be a few folders deep, so this has to be done recursively.

But I would like for `Dir.glob` to stop at the first occurence, and not continue going through all the other folders. How could I accomplish this?

This is my code right now:

```
def find_installs
  installs = []
  glob_dir = @config[:install_folders]
  Dir.glob("#{glob_dir}**/install_file.md").each do |install_file|
    installs << File.dirname(install_file).gsub(glob_dir, "")
  end

  installs
end
```

Is there another class that I could use that provides this functionality?

By the way, the code has to run on Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: perfect lib is - http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/find/rdoc/Find.html

Comment: @ArupRakshit I should've mentioned it should be 1.9.3 compatible.

Comment: it is available in 1.9.3 - http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/find/rdoc/Find.html

Comment: @ArupRakshit nice, let me have a go at it. You might as well put it as an answer

Comment: I am not understanding well your intention, but understood which lib you can use.. so give it to you.. :)..

Comment: what do you mean by *the first occurence* ? may be you write your code and post it as an answer.. I am not understanding where to stop, and from where you want to stop.. etc

Comment: @ArupRakshit I wanted to back out of a directory, and continue on the next one, if that directory has the file `install_file.md`. But your `Find` module really helped a lot. So if you were to post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Okay.. I will.. Give some moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Required lib is [`Find`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/find/rdoc/Find.html).

I have created a Folder structure as follows :-

```
/folder1/
|- folder2/
     |-folder21/
        |-a.txt
     |-a.txt
|- folder3/
     |-folder31/
        |-a.txt
     |-a.txt
```

Now I write the code below to meet OP's need :-

```
require 'find'

path_find = '/home/kirti/workspace/folder1'

Find.find(path_find) do |path|
  if FileTest.directory?(path)
    unless Dir["#{path}/a.txt"].empty?
      p "#{path}/a.txt"
      Find.prune # Don't look any further into this directory.
    else
      next
    end
  else
    # nothing
  end
end
# >> "/home/kirti/workspace/folder1/folder2/a.txt"
# >> "/home/kirti/workspace/folder1/folder3/a.txt"
```

You can see `folder21` also contains `a.txt` file, but as `folder2` contains `a.txt`, no search made into the sub-directory `folder21`. Same explanation applicable for `folder3` and its sub-directory `folder31`.